# If condition associated with applying a column filter

Tags: vba, if-statement, filter

I'm trying to use an if-condition regarding filters. I wish I could write a code to check if a specific filter is applied and then do something... (of course)

My first attempt was:

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("$D$4:$Q$20").AutoFilter Field:=2 then
   Rows("22:22").Select
   Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

In the very first line, VBA doesn't accept the condition that is written...

Any guess?

tks

Comment: It doesn't work Ben =/

Answer (score 2):

This will tell you if a range is in a filter and the filter is active:

```
Public Function IsFilterOn(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iFilterNum As Integer

    Set ws = rng.Parent

    If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(rng, ws.AutoFilter.Range) Is Nothing Then
            With ws.AutoFilter.Filters
                iFilterNum = rng.Column - .Item(1).Parent.Range.Column + 1

                If iFilterNum <= .Count Then
                    IsFilterOn = .Item(iFilterNum).On
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't need to select a row before hiding it.

```
Sub HideWhenFiltered()
    With ActiveSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            If .AutoFilter.Filters(2).On Then
               .Rows(22).Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```